# Is it possible to define resource labels for OCI load balancers deployed via OKE Kubernetes Ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I need to add labels to the Oracle Cloud Load Balancer resources deployed through OKE Kubernetes Nginx Ingress controllers. Is this possible from the Kubernetes manifest?

Thanks,

Alexander

Comment: Can you share your current manifest? What labels do you want to add? Add more information on what you would like to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported today, but will be at some point in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @user2276143. Are you associated with OCI or OKE? It would be good to have something official.

Comment: For something official, you should open a ticket with OCI support.

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to define OCI Load Balancer resource 'initial' namespaced and freeform tags through Kubernetes annotations.

OCI documentation and examples -

https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/ContEng/Tasks/contengtaggingclusterresources.htm#contengtaggingclusterresources_tagging_oke_resources_load_balancer_tags

I have successfully tested this.